# How to create a global array in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a global array by converting a table into an array in the first code, and then calling it in the second code. However, i get a run-time error '13' type mismatch when calling my second code.

```
Public prio_row_num
Public prioritytbl As Variant

Sub Tabletoarray()

Dim prioritytbl As Variant

Worksheets("Prod_met").Activate

prioritytbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("prioritylist").DataBodyRange.Value

End Sub

Sub test()

MsgBox (prioritytbl(2, 2))

End Sub
```

I want to be able to call the prioritytbl in subsequent parts of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use Global variables if possible. Let's give you an example on how could you do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Tabletoarray()

    Dim prioritytbl As Variant
    prioritytbl = Worksheets("Prod_met").ListObjects("prioritylist").DataBodyRange.Value
    Call test(prioritytbl)

End Sub
Sub test(prioritytbl As Variant)

    MsgBox (prioritytbl(2, 2))

End Sub
```

Said this, if you need to use the global variable, you can't declare it again in any sub:

```
Option Explicit
Public prio_row_num
Public prioritytbl As Variant

Sub Tabletoarray()

' Dim prioritytbl As Variant this needs to be deleted

    prioritytbl = Worksheets("Prod_met").ListObjects("prioritylist").DataBodyRange.Value

End Sub
Sub test()

    MsgBox (prioritytbl(2, 2))

End Sub
```

I would also recommend you to read on [how to avoid using .select or .activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)